# Change behaviour of credentials when in non-interactive mode

Tags: powershell, credentials, powershell-5.0

Given a function which takes a parameter to supress prompting for user input (e.g. `NonInteractive`), is there any way to change the behaviour of `[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]` such that if it's passed a username as a string it throws an exception instead of prompting for a password?

```
function Test-NonInteractiveCredential {
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()] 
        $Credential = [PSCredential]::Empty
        ,        
        [Parameter()]
        [Switch]$NonInteractive
    )
    if ($Credential -eq [PSCredential]::Empty) {
        "no credentials specified"
    } else {
        "User: $($Credential.username); Pass: $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"
    }
}
```

NB: I tried testing this using PowerShell's own command line `NonInteractive` parameter; but even with that PS still prompts.

```
powershell -noninteractive -command "function demo{param([System.Management.Automation.Credential()][PSCredential]$cred)process{$cred -eq $null;$cred.username}}; demo -cred 'demoUser'"
```

This is the best workaround I've come up with:

```
function Test-NonInteractiveCredential {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Interactive')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Interactive')]
        [PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()] #only included on the interactive version; so the non-interactive version would error if only a string were given
        $Credential = [PSCredential]::Empty
        ,        
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'NonInteractive')]
        [PSCredential]
        $NonInteractiveCredential = [PSCredential]::Empty #we can't have a parameter with the same name
        ,        
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'NonInteractive')]
        [Switch]$NonInteractive
    )
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'NonInteractive') {
        $Credential = $NonInteractiveCredential 
    }
    if ($Credential -eq [PSCredential]::Empty) {
        "no credentials specified"
    } else {
        "User: $($Credential.username); Pass: $($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)"
    }
}
```

...but this is not ideal since we have to have a separate parameter (i.e. we can't just include the `Credential` parameter in both parameter sets, since the attribute should only be used in one, and so far as I can tell there's no way to amend this behaviour per parameter set.

NB: This is a question from curiosity / purely academic; there's no real world issue that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Ugh, this sucks (the situation, not your question). Your workaround is pretty good but for not being ale to use the same name. I feel like the only way to get around that is probably to use `DynamicParam` and add the credential attribute dynamically based on whether the switch is provided. I'm not sure if that would even work consistently.

Comment: If PowerShell still prompts even when `-NonInteractive` is in use, this seems like a bug...

Comment: I encountered something similar once, and ended up spawning a new powershell process with craziness: https://superuser.com/a/621638

Comment: Hm, so here's something weird maybe. In my testing, PowerShell is prompting for the password when a user name is supplied, even when the `[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]` attribute isn't present. Anyone else seeing that?

Comment: @briantist good point; I get the same; hadn't even thought to test that.  (PSVersion: 5.1.14409.1012, BuildVersion: 10.0.14409.1012)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart agreed; will log both of these behaviours at: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/ ...

Comment: Prompting without `[Credential()]` bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5583

Comment: Prompting with `[Credential()]` in `NonInteractive` mode bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5584

Comment: Thanks also @briantist; I've not played with dynamic parameters yet / was looking for a legitimate excuse to; so this seems a good moment.  Great suggestion.